# I can not use "content://sms"?

Tags: android

I can not use "content://sms"?
Works on all Android devices?
I'm using "SmsManager" but does not add sms in the phone box output.
I use the "content://sms/outbox" to save the information.
How can I using the "SmsManager"?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to send an SMS? By adding it to "content://sms/outbox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you send the message you have to write the SMS to the cr.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", phone);
values.put("body", message);
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

This requires the sms write permission, and has to be completed after the sms is sent.

Comment: I can use "content://sms/sent"? Works on all Android devices?